# Sending a notification to the users on their birthday (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have a small question and would really appreciate any help.
If the user gives permissions to the app, and app stores his/her birthday along with long-term access token. Will my app be able to send the notification (congratulations on your birthday) using this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications ?

Even, if I give permission i.e. on Dec and my birthday is on Aug, and I haven't used the app since the Dec, will I get the notification?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can

If you read the documentation, the token used by this api is **app access token**. But just one thing you should note that this api is only for the canvas apps.